# Mapa do Brasil em SVG para WindowsPhone. Tem como?

Tags: windows-phone, xaml

É possível utilizar Paths (os mesmos do SVG) para se criar um mapa do Brasil no WindowsPhone?

Alguem possui algum exemplo?

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tem um mapa em SVG feito para WindowsPhone

O código C# deve ficar assim:

```
private void OnPathTap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    // Cor padrão dos elementos do mapa
    Color cor = ConvertStringToColor("#007acc");

    // Recupera todos os elementos "Path" do mapa
    var listaPaths = FindControls<Path>(gridMapa);

    // Altera a cor de todos os elementos novamente para a cor padrão
    if (listaPaths != null)
    {
        foreach (Path item in listaPaths)
        {
            item.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(cor);
        }
    }

    // Recupera o elemento Path selecionado
    Path path = (Path)sender;
    if (path != null)
    {
        // Altera a cor do elemento
        path.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Busca uma lista de controles dentro de outro controle.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Tipo a ser buscado.</typeparam>
/// <param name="parentElement">Controle pai.</param>
/// <returns>Controle.</returns>
public List<T> FindControls<T>(DependencyObject targetElement) where T : DependencyObject
{
    var result = new List<T>();

    var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(targetElement);
    if (count == 0)
        return new List<T>();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(targetElement, i);
        if (child is T)
        {
            result.Add(child as T);
        }
        else
        {
            result = FindControls<T>(child);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

/// <summary>
/// Conmverte uma cor em Hexadecimal para System.Windows.Media.Color.
/// Referência: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11739523/1509954
/// </summary>
/// <param name="hex"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public Color ConvertStringToColor(String hex)
{
    //remove the # at the front
    hex = hex.Replace("#", "");

    byte a = 255;
    byte r = 255;
    byte g = 255;
    byte b = 255;

    int start = 0;

    //handle ARGB strings (8 characters long)
    if (hex.Length == 8)
    {
        a = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(0, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        start = 2;
    }

    //convert RGB characters to bytes
    r = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(start, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    g = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(start + 2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    b = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(start + 4, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

    return Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b);
}
```

Basicamente é feito utilizando os Paths do SVG normal, que deve ficar semelhante ao fragmento a seguir:

```
    <Viewbox Margin="10">
        <Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Name="gridMapa">
            <Path Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1" Tap="OnPathTap" Data="M30.47,237.77L28.39, etc... etc..." Fill="#FF007acc" />
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
```

Código completo do [mapa do Brasil em SVG](https://github.com/WashingtonMorais/WindowsPhone)

Comment: Recomendo editar o exemplo do github, pois está misturando o xaml com o cs, poderia fornecer um exemplo pronto para usar?